# How to import files relative to main file, instead of current directory? ((Chez) Scheme)

Tags: import, scheme, chez-scheme

For example, in my `main.scm` file I have `(load "util.scm")`. `util.scm` is a file in the same folder as `main.scm`. Both files are located in `~/documents/myproject/`.

Now when I'm in this directory, and I run `$ chez-scheme main.scm` everything works fine. However, if I'm in my home directory and run `$chez-scheme documents/myproject/main.scm` it complains, not being able to find the file `util.scm`. I suppose this is the case because the current directory was my relevant home directory, and as such `util.scm` is indeed not there, it is actually in `documents/myproject/`. That being said, I'm used (in other languages) to the functionality of looking these paths up relative to the file containing the instruction to import, and I'd like to have that here as well. I've tried prefixing it by `./` or defining the file as a libary and doing `(import (util))` but none of it works outside of `documents/myproject/`. Is there any way to get this to work as I intend it to?

I assume this is Chez-Scheme-specific. If not I'd prefer an answer that is implementation-neutral.

Answer (score 2):

`load` is kind of awkward in R5RS since the report states that system interfaces are off topic in the report, but they include `load` which is a half hearted solution. The report does not say if the `load` is relative to the current directory or the file the `load` form originates from so in order to be portable I guess you are required to run your script from the current directory and have your loaded file relative to both.

Since Chez Scheme implements R6RS `load` is not really the right form to use. R6RS removed `load` in favor of libraries. You should make your file a library and consult how to install it. In some systems that is just placing the files in the right path, adding library location in configuration or running install script. How one uses the library is the same in all implementations, by using `import`.

According to [Chez documentation](http://scheme.com/csug8/use.html#g9) you can pass `--libdirs` to it to give it one or more paths to consider for loading libraries. You can see the paths it scans by evaluating `(library-directories)`

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways to accomplish what (I think) you are trying to do, but eventually they all boil down to letting Chez know where to look for things.  When given relative paths, `include` and `load` use the `source-directories` parameter to search for the requested file.  Libraries have their path automatically prepended to `source-directories` while they are being loaded or compiled, so if your `main.scm` were a library definition then it would find `util.scm` as you expect.

However, it sounds like `main.scm` isn't a library, it's a top-level program.  Unfortunately, Chez doesn't have a command line option to set the `source-directories` like it does for library directories.  That leaves you with a bit less flexibility.  Any of the following will work:

- Make `util.scm` a library and invoke Chez with the `--libdirs` option to let it know where to look for libraries.
- Set `source-directories` and load `main.scm` from inside the REPL rather than from the command line.
- Write a wrapper shell script that does the above by echoing the commands into `scheme` so you don't have to type it yourself.  (Only suitable if you don't also need to then type into the scheme session).
- Write a wrapper shell script that `cd`s into your project directory before running `scheme` (and presumably `cd`s back to the original directory when it's done).